# Joining two queries or a union /union all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a union all from the below code.  I am not sure this is what I want.  The top portion in is group down into smaller detail. It counts the number of  students, by school,grade, test scores by engProf and ethnic .  the second query gives a total conut of students broken down by student,school,grade and test taken. Returning the total number of second grade students at school x took the math test, and x students took the reading test. One will be a higher level summary of the other.  I want to join them together for one dataset to be used in a report.  Any suggestions.  I tried a union all not sure if that is the best solution.

---

```
SELECT 
track,
schoolc,
schname AS[school],
grade,
subtestc AS[ELA/Math],
EngProf,
SUM(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [total Students],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('A','P') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [At/Above],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('B','BB','FBB') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Below],
SUM(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND(ethnic)='White (not Hispanic)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total White(not Hispanic)],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('A','P') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND(ethnic)='White (not Hispanic)'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [White (Total not Hispanic) At/Above],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('B','BB','FBB') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND(ethnic)='White (not Hispanic)'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ Total White (not Hispanic)],
SUM(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND(ethnic) <>'White (not Hispanic)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ Total Other Nonwhite students],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('A','P') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND (ethnic)<>'White (not Hispanic)'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [TotalOther Non_White At/Above],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('B','BB','FBB') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND (ethnic)<>'White (not Hispanic)'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Other Non-White Below],
NULL AS [Grand total Students]

FROM [dbo].[qw_star_testing_detail]
WHERE subtestc IN('ela','Math')
AND tscrtypc ='A' 
AND testscore NOT IN('9')
GROUP BY track,
schoolc,
schname,
track,
grade,
EngProf,
subtestc


UNION ALL 

SELECT 
track,--NULL AS [track],schoolc,     
schoolc, ---NULL AS [schoolc],
schname AS[school],---NULL AS[school],
grade,---NULL AS [grade,],
subtestc AS[ELA/Math],--NULL AS[ELA/Math],
NULL AS[engProf],
null AS [total Students],
null AS [At/Above],
NULL AS [Below],
null AS [Total White(not Hispanic)],
NULL as [White (Total not Hispanic) At/Above],
null AS [ Total White (not Hispanic)],
NULL AS [ Total Other Nonwhite students],
null AS [TotalOther Non_White At/Above],
null AS [Total Other Non-White Below],
SUM(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Grand total Students]

FROM [dbo].[qw_star_testing_detail]
WHERE subtestc IN('ela','Math')
AND tscrtypc ='A' 
AND testscore NOT IN('9')
GROUP BY track,
schoolc,
schname,
track,
grade,
--EngProf,
subtestc
--ethnic
```

---

---

Comment: Are you pulling the results of this query into a Reporting package for formatting?  If so, then you should be able to extract at the more detailed records and use your reporting package to add groupings and aggregate values for the details

Comment: I'm confused, your from and where and group by clauses look the same to me.  Am I missing something? Why do you need a union or a join?  It seems to me that you could just move your only sum from the second query to the first one, replacing the null version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just want to left outer join the 2?
Where the left table has the finer grain (more detail).

You could use a CTE.

```
With
Group1
AS
(SELECT 
track,
schoolc,
schname AS[school],
grade,
subtestc AS[ELA/Math],
EngProf,
SUM(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [total Students],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('A','P') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [At/Above],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('B','BB','FBB') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Below],
SUM(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND(ethnic)='White (not Hispanic)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total White(not Hispanic)],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('A','P') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND(ethnic)='White (not Hispanic)'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [White (Total not Hispanic) At/Above],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('B','BB','FBB') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND(ethnic)='White (not Hispanic)'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ Total White (not Hispanic)],
SUM(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND(ethnic) <>'White (not Hispanic)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [ Total Other Nonwhite students],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('A','P') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND (ethnic)<>'White (not Hispanic)'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [TotalOther Non_White At/Above],
SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('B','BB','FBB') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A' AND (ethnic)<>'White (not Hispanic)'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Other Non-White Below],
NULL AS [Grand total Students]

FROM [dbo].[qw_star_testing_detail]
WHERE subtestc IN('ela','Math')
AND tscrtypc ='A' 
AND testscore NOT IN('9')
GROUP BY track,
schoolc,
schname,
track,
grade,
EngProf,
subtestc)
,
Group2
AS
(SELECT 
track,--NULL AS [track],schoolc,     
schoolc, ---NULL AS [schoolc],
schname AS[school],---NULL AS[school],
grade,---NULL AS [grade,],
subtestc AS[ELA/Math],--NULL AS[ELA/Math],
NULL AS[engProf],
null AS [total Students],
null AS [At/Above],
NULL AS [Below],
null AS [Total White(not Hispanic)],
NULL as [White (Total not Hispanic) At/Above],
null AS [ Total White (not Hispanic)],
NULL AS [ Total Other Nonwhite students],
null AS [TotalOther Non_White At/Above],
null AS [Total Other Non-White Below],
SUM(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Grand total Students]

FROM [dbo].[qw_star_testing_detail]
WHERE subtestc IN('ela','Math')
AND tscrtypc ='A' 
AND testscore NOT IN('9')
GROUP BY track,
schoolc,
schname,
track,
grade,
--EngProf,
subtestc
--ethnic)

Select group1.track,   
group1.schoolc, group1.[school]
,group2. whatever other fields you want
From Group1
Left outer join Group2
 ON Group1.track=group2.track
 AND Group1.schoolc=group2.schoolc
 and group1.school = group2.school
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common practice with one trick... Add in an order or level column to get the results in the right order.  Don't have nulls for the items that you are grouping by because you can't order it right.  Here is a example where I am making a list of a class students and total count:

```
   SELECT class, student_name, count
   FROM
   (
     SELECT class, student_name, 0 as count, 1 as ord
     FROM classlist
     UNION ALL
     SELECT class, '' as student_name, count() as count, 2 as ord
     FROM classlist
     GROUP BY class
   ) T
   ORDER BY class, ord, student_name
```